# hex to bin converter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a textbox which takes as input hex values and a messagebox which shows the output in binary. For example:

> input  : F710(string)
>   output : 1111011100010000

I will use that value in another work. How could I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How have you tried to do it? How did it not work?

Comment: i am trying to create an enum which will define 0-f's bin value.
enum hex
        {                    
            0=0000,
            1=0001,
            2=0010,
            3=0011,
            4=0100,
            5=0101,
            6=0110,
            7=0111,
            8=1000,
            9=1001,
            A=1010,
            a=1010,
            B=1011,
            b=1011,
            C=1100,
            c=1100,
            D=1101,
            d=1101,
            E=1110,
            e=1110,
            F=1111,
            f=1111
        };

Comment: I'm not sure an `enum` is really what you're after, since it is limited to defining _integers_ -- what you want is probably a character -> string mapping... right?

Comment: yes. you are right. than what to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more careful with the tags you select; this question has absolutely zero content pertaining to Visual Studio, and it's more a general C# question than a specific version, since the question could be answered easily in code compatible with C# 1.0. I removed the Visual Studio tag and added the general C# one in order to try and get you help. Limiting tags to those that actually apply to your question helps get faster answers and avoids cluttering search results with noise. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure if I understand your question, but the easiest thing that comes to mind is to just calculate the values on the fly. For example:

```
public static string BitStringFromHexString(string hex)
{
    int i;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out i))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Input not recognized '{0}'. ", hex), "hex");
    }

    return Convert.ToString(i,2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string binV = "";
        binV = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text, 16), 2);
        textBox2.Text=binV;
```

Should do the job for ya.